# PHP+MySQL: Creating a photo gallery based on views

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to create a system where the user can go to a page where a photo is displayed. The photos have a column in the MySQL db for views. How would I be able to view the top viewed photo with a link on the page for the photo with the 2nd most viewed photo, which has a link for the 3rd most viewed photo, etc. Each photo would have a dedicated page.

I'm using CakePHP, if there are any CakePHP specific strategies for doing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never had the experience of using cakePHP, but with PHP and MySQL, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT image_link, view_count
FROM `tablename`
ORDER BY view_count DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET $i;
```

and then, using a GET variable to pass on the incremental/decremental value of `$i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect statistics for each image using

```
<?php
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

where $url - is a full path for your image.

Answer (score 0):

well i don't have knowledge of cakephp, but i am telling you the logic to achieve that you want,

just send some parameter on the photo click and set a unique id of the photos, so that on the click event on the photo you will get the unique id of the photo and get which photo is viewed and update the database on every click.

beside that the link you will genrate according to your requiement to fetch the image on view filed on descending order

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, although my "view" system has already been implemented